# Google Page Speed

Tags: javascript, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, optimization

My website is in Wordpress so I am asking question regarding Google Page Speed here.

My issue is i had completed the development of home page of existing page now when i am trying to check the score of my home page it showing me the Old list of Javascripts which i had used erlier. so how can I improve the score and remove that blocking scripts.

I am using Autoptimize & W3 Total Cache Plugin to optimize.

FYI Website URL:
Actual Home page : https://www.hitechcaddservices.com/
Newly Design Home Page : https://www.hitechcaddservices.com/home-2/

I am providing both URL, in case you might visit this thread after i had moved the newly design home page to actual one so you can view that.

Thanks in advances, any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing your website's cache

Comment: It looks like it's already been resolved - I just ran a page speed and it got a 94.

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. i had tried it now score is fluctuating in between 55 to 80. and it showing me autoptimized js as blocking resource so how to remove it?